# How do you count how many documents are in a cluster?

Tags: python, mongodb, count, discord, document

(discord.py, mongodb)

I'm trying to find how many documents in this specific cluster, I tried using the `db.collection.count()` line in

```
db = cluster["databaseTest"]
collection = db["timers"]

timer_info = {"Length": atime, "Created at": ctx.message.created_at, "Custom_thing": "hi"}
collection.insert_one(timer_info)

timer_amount = db.collection.count("Custom_thing":"hi")
```

I'm not getting any errors, but it keeps saying that timer_amount = 0, even though there are other documents in there.

Comment: Did you have a look at [db.collection.count()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/) documentation?

Comment: Tried using timer_amount = db.collection.aggregate([{$count: "timers"}]) but it says that $count is invalid syntax